# Refactoring If statement to be less verbose in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a more concise way of structuring the following `if` statement?

```
if self.itemsize.downcase.include? "a3" or 
   self.itemsize.downcase.include? "a4" or 
   self.itemsize.downcase.include? "a5" or 
   self.itemsize.downcase.include? "dl" 

  puts "yadda yadda"

end
```

Perhaps with an array?   eg `if self.itemsize.downcase.include? ["a3", "a4", "a5", "dl"]`

Comment: looks like you answered your own question.

Comment: @Hunter: `String#include` doesn't work with an array argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution with a regular expression:

```
if self.itemsize =~ /(a3|a4|a5|dl)/i
#if self.itemsize =~ /\A(a3|a4|a5|dl)\Z/i
  puts "yadda yadda"

end
```

Answer (score 8):

```
size = itemsize.downcase # memoize
if %w(a3 a4 a5 dl).any? {|e| size.include? e}
  puts "yadda yadda"
end
```

Comment: Why use `any?` here? How about `%w(a3 a4 a5 dl).include?(size)` (like randomguy suggests)?

Comment: `a.include?(b) != b.include?(a)`, so that is wrong, read the question again.

Comment: @mischa: Because it's the opposite of what OP asks. See clyfe's comment on randomguy's answer.

Comment: This works great!  Its a little more verbose than @knut regex answer.  Both solutions are correct, however I can only accept one.  Thanks heaps :)

Answer (score 3):

How I'd probably do it:

```
p "yadda yadda" if ["a3", "a4", "a5", "dl"].include?(self.itemsize.downcase)
```

I would move the array to a class/module variable so that it's not instantiated every time.

EDIT:

What OP actually wants is to test if any of the strings `"a3", "a4", "a5", "dl"` is a sub-string of `self.itemsize.downcase`. The above tests if self.itemsize.downcase is equal to any of the strings, which is different from the former. Thanks clyfe for pointing that out.

Comment: NOTICE: `a.include?(b) != b.include?(a)` read the question more carefully!